# Android event listener for app lifecycle

Tags: android, listener

I am writing an Android code segment to help tracing Android event as a service tool for app developers.

For example, the main app body can be just to display 'hello world'. My code will listen to the app event, such as `onStart()`, `onResume()`, `onDestroy()`, etc, and keep a trace on these events.

Certainly, the code can be inserted directly under the main activity. But that means my code will be allover the places. Is there a way, I can create an object (i.e., a listener), and only request the app developer to add 1~2 liner to use my code?

Answer (score 19):

For API Level 14 and higher, you can [call `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks()` on the `Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks%28android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks%29) to set up a listener to be informed about activity lifecycle events.

Comment: thanks. registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks() probably the right one I am looking for.

Comment: See Cornstalk's answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/android-is-application-running-in-background/5862048 - for a nice example of how to use it.

Answer (score 7):

Try this Approach

```
public class mYApplication extends Application {

 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new MyLifecycleHandler());

     }

}
```

**MyLifecycleHandler :**

```
public class MyLifecycleHandler implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    private static int resumed;
    private static int paused;
    private static int started;
    private static int stopped;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        ++resumed;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
        ++paused;
        android.util.Log.w("test", "application is in foreground: " + (resumed > paused));
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
        ++started;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
        ++stopped;
        android.util.Log.w("test", "application is visible: " + (started > stopped));
    }

    public static boolean isApplicationVisible() {
        return started > stopped;
    }

    public static boolean isApplicationInForeground() {
        return resumed > paused;
    }


}
```

and then call  `isApplicationInForeground` static method to check if application is in foreground or background