# App open or background (to show notification or not)

Tags: android

I have my app that receives a GCM message from the server.  I got all that working with notification coming up.

My issue is that if the app is open then I don't want to show notification and just display show the message withing the app. But if the app is closed then I need to show notification ( like a chat app).

How can I do this determination?

Thanks

Comment: there is no way to determine it except manually - create some flag somewhere, and track your app's activities' lifecycle to check if any activity is in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if app is in background or not try this.

```
 public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
    boolean isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                    if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                        isInBackground = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            isInBackground = false;
        }
    }

    return isInBackground;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an listener for Activity lifecycle events to your Application object.

See here
[Android event listener for app lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046905/android-event-listener-for-app-lifecycle)

[Checking if an Android application is running in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/checking-if-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-background/5862048#5862048)