# How to Launch specific activity when my Application is in Recent Apps List?

Tags: android, android-recents

in my android application 3 activities are there.those are A,B&C.
Initial landing screen is A.then navigate to B.
But I want to display Activity C when this app is in recent appslist kind of App Masking.
Any one have idea please share me.
Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Well it's easy you can use the **savedInstanceState** Bundle to save a boolean flag(lest say isAppCameFromRecent) in **onSavedInstanceState** method when app minimised then use **onRestoreInstanceState** to extract that boolean when app returns from recent apps list if boolean is set to true then navigate to activity C.

@

```
Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState); 
     ...
    }

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
...
}
```

Comment: I want to display another screen when we look the app in recent apps list  if we open the app I want normal behaviour kind of App Mask screen

Answer (score 0):

you can `StartActivity` C Activity in onResume of A Or B activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046905/android-event-listener-for-app-lifecycle)** check in on resume check weather your **Activity** exits in **ActivityManager**.

Comment: i have started another activity at onpause even though that layout not visible at recent apps.New layout is visible after open the app, But i want to change the UI when app is in recent apps(cards view)